# Although not [required] List field shows up as required and Model State is not Valid due to it being null?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, field, required-field

I have the following code-

View-

```
<% Html.BeginForm(); %>
    <div>
<%= Html.DropDownList("DropDownSelectList", new SelectList( Model.DropDownSelectList, "Value", "Text"))%>
```

Controller-

```
public ActionResult Admin(string apiKey, string userId)
{
    ChallengesAdminViewModel vm = new ChallengesAdminViewModel();
    vm.ApiKey = apiKey;
    vm.UserId = userId;
    vm.DropDownSelectList = new List<SelectListItem>();
    vm.DropDownSelectList.Add(listItem1);
    vm.DropDownSelectList.Add(listItem2);
    vm.DropDownSelectList.Add(listItem3);
    vm.DropDownSelectList.Add(listItem4);
    vm.DropDownSelectList.Add(listItem5);
    vm.DropDownSelectList.Add(listItem6);
    vm.DropDownSelectList.Add(listItem7);
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Admin(ChallengesAdminViewModel vm)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)//Due to the null dropdownlist  gives model state invalid
    {
    }
}
```

ViewModel-

```
public class ChallengesAdminViewModel
{
    [Required]
    public string ApiKey { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string UserId { get; set; }

    public List<SelectListItem> DropDownSelectList { get; set; }  
}
```

I dont know why it still requires the list although not required. I want to have only two attributes as required. So I wanted to know how do i declare or change that list to be not required and have my Model State Valid.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The way I do it is have a property in my view model that the dropdown will be bound to (which is nullable) and then have a separate property that contains all the options for the drop down.

ViewModel properties

```
public int? CountryId { get; set; }
public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> CountryOptions { get; set; }
```

View

```
<label for="CountryId">Country:</label>
<%: Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.CountryId, Model.CountryOptions, "N/A")%>
```

Note: The `"N/A"` string is the default empty value.

HTHs,
Charles

Ps. This is of course using ASP.NET MVC 2

Comment: Pointing out that you should validate that the value of your "placeholder field" (`CountryId`) is one of the possible values in the dropdown (`CountryOptions`); otherwise I think you can change the HTML to submit a completely different value.

Answer (score 0):

The simple answer would be to remove it from your model and pass it via ViewData instead.  Then, your model would contain a member for the value that was selected from the list.

Comment: Well..actually that is what i did....but i just wanted to know why it was [required] field even when i didnt set it to be.

Comment: @mxmissile - have a look at my answer for a *no magic string* version.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's failing because it can't coerce a single value (`""`) into a `SelectListItem` to put into a list.  You can only ever have one `DropDownSelectList` value selected.

You might try making your `ChallengesAdminViewModel.DropDownSelectList` of type string instead. Then it will be the value of the selected option. `SelectListItems` are made for pushing options to the view, not parsing the posted result.